# If $(m,n)\in\left(\mathbb{N}^*\right)^2$, is there $(j,k,r)\in\left(\mathbb{N}^*\right)^3$ such that $\;r>\max(m,n)$ ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $(m,n)\in\left(\mathbb{N}^*\right)^2$, is there $(j,k,r)\in\left(\mathbb{N}^*\right)^3$ such that : $\;r>\max(m,n)$ $\; , \;$ $\gcd(10,r)=1$ , $10^j\equiv m\mod r\;$ and $\;10^k\equiv n\mod r$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The following is an observation, not a solution. Assume the [Artin Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) on primitive roots. This says that every number other than perfect squares and $-1$ is a primitive root for infinitely many primes.  That implies, in particular, that $10$ is a primitive root for infinitely many primes.

If we take  $r$ to be such a prime greater than $m$ or $n$, the result follows immediately.